# Silverlight WebClient NOT receiving 400 Bad Request

Tags: silverlight, facebook-graph-api, webclient

I have a WebClient and I'm subscribing to the OnDownloadStringCompleted event handler. When the server responds with a header of 400 Bad Request, the OnDownloadStringCompleted Never gets triggered.  I still need what the response is even though the header says 400.  Is there a way to bypass this?

Heres the URL I'm attempting to fetch:
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=your_token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all in my testing I find that the DownloadStringCompleted does fire.

However an attempt to read the event args `Result` property will throw an error.  You need to test the event args `Error` property to determine if an error occured.  If it has this property will hold a reference to a `WebException`.

Fortunately the `WebException` has a `Response` object which is of type `WebResponse`.  You can get the response string from this using a little function:-

```
    string StringFromWebResponse(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

But there is a problem.  This is only available when using the ClientHTTP stack not the BrowserHTTP stack.  So you need something like this line of code in your app:-

```
    WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://graph.facebook.com", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

So then code like this will work:-

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
        {
            string result;

            if (args.Error == null)
            {
                result = args.Result;
                //Do something with the expected result
            }
            else
            {
                WebException err = args.Error as WebException;

                result = StringFromWebResponse(err.Response);
                // Do something with the error result
            }
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=your_token", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Oh but there is possibly another problem.  I don't know anything about the facebook API but if there is a dependency on cookies then by default the ClientHTTP stack doesn't manage cookies itself.  To handle cookies properly you need to assign a common `CookieContainer` to each `HttpWebRequest` used.  `WebClient` doesn't allow you access to the `WebRequest` object used so you'll need to drop to using `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` directly.

Comment: The RegisterPrefix seems to have done it.  For some reason it would  not trigger on the Error 400, but with the prefix it does.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Peanut:  I tested without ClientHTTP and the event does still fire, it would be a serious fault IMO if it did not fire at all.  If you are able to demonstrate it not firing it would be good if you could create a small Repro of it and include it in the question.